# Vim shell command messages output printed outside vim editor

Tags: shell, vim, stdio

Normally, whenever I enter shell command like `!ls` or `rm file` in vim, the message along with confirmation prompt will be printed below vim status line. My issue is, when I'm doing shell command, the message is printed out outside vim editor (like it was minimized) and then bring me back to the editor after I press enter button to confirm. What is causing this to happen?

**UPDATE**

This is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: What you want is a GVim/MacVim-only feature. What you see is how Vim is supposed to work in a terminal.

Comment: It didn't happen before I installed some plugins, like airline, tabline, bufferline and tmuxline.

Comment: Then temporarily disable these plugins in turn, find out which one is responsible for the behaviour you're accusing, and post a bug report to its issue tracker.

Comment: I've tried that. I've even tried to remove `.vimrc` file, but it still happens. I don't know why, but it's not like that before. It's not leaving vim to background before.

Comment: When run in a terminal, Vim *never* does what you want.

Comment: @romainl Actually it can. I update my question with a screen shot. I installed Ubuntu without desktop in virtualbox, just to test it. It runs vim in terminal and show the output below vim editor, not outside. And the problem is, I can't get that behaviour back to my main machine.

Comment: That behavior is dictated by your `TERM`: set it to `linux` (the default on virtual consoles like in your screenshot) and you will get what you want. Terminal emulators usually have their `TERM` set to `xterm` or some variant which works *very* differently from `linux`.